# High Power RF Detector Circuit

Tags: rf, detector

I was tasked to work on an 'RF Detector Circuit' for work. The circuit has an input RF power of 72 Watts at a 7.5GHz frequency through an 8mm wire. It's supposes to reduce that power and voltage, and be able to illuminate an LED. For the LED I was told to use a Lumex SML LX3939WWC-TR, Schottky power diodes, BZX55C9V5 for the zeners and 10W caps. The circuit I was instructed to use is attached below.

It's been years since I've played with circuits and I can't remember how to be able to pick appropriate values for the resistors and caps to be able to couple to the input specs. This is not my primary job either, just something I was tasked with on the side. Any resources pointing me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Detector Circuit]

Comment: Is the LED only supposed to light up if the input is at a certain power? Or frequency? What is the circuit supposed to "detect"?

Comment: I believe it is supposed to light up when it is at the desired frequency... I'm sorry I'm still really trying to understand it myself; it's one of those projects that was thrown in my way without clear instructions.

Comment: What connector does your circuit have, for 70 W at 7.5 GHz?

Comment: If you have no clear instructions as to what this is meant to do then how can anyone possibly understand how to help you?

Comment: They can't...But I'm still so confused. I'll see what other info I can get tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that circuit is rubbish. The LED will never light up.

I assume that your "8mm wire" is in fact a [quarter-wave monopole antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Quarter-wave_monopole). As such, it will have a feed-point impedance of about 36Ω. From this, you can calculate the voltage and current available:

$$V_{RMS} = \sqrt{P \cdot R} = 51V$$

$$I_{RMS} = \sqrt{P / R} = 1.4A$$

You're going to have to set up a power divider so that only about 1/3600 of this power goes through the LED.

Comment: A power divider circuit with the LED at the output replacing this one?

Comment: I won't comment further until you come up with a clearer description of the purpose of the circuit. If it's supposed to discriminate the frequency, then the circuit you were given is *complete* rubbish.

Comment: @DaveTweed - You also forgot to mention the Schottky power diodes operating at 7.5 GHz. Yeah, that'll work.

Comment: @whatroughbeast Simple 70 W 7 GHz detector: 1) bend LED legs open, 2) place in front of radar, 3) replace burned-out LED with a new one with legs cut shorter. 4) You're done. I'd draw a circuit diagram but I'm on my mobile.

Comment: Im so confused... :(